# Never getting uploading data progress in google API for ios

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, google-drive-api

I am using GoogleDrive API in my application to upload files from my application. So far I succeeded and finding good results for uploading all types of files.

I followed [Google example](https://developers.google.com/drive/examples/objectivec) to upload files.

I am trying to show the progress, dependent on file size, while uploading. I have gone through many classes in the google given example code but there isn't much result.

**Steps  followed to get the file uploading progress :**

I have found below method In GTLServices.m

```
- (void)setUploadProgressBlock:(GTLServiceUploadProgressBlock)block {
  [uploadProgressBlock_ autorelease];
  uploadProgressBlock_ = [block copy];

  if (uploadProgressBlock_) {
    // As above, we need the fetcher to call us back when bytes are sent.
    SEL sentDataSel = @selector(objectFetcher:didSendBytes:totalBytesSent:totalBytesExpectedToSend:);
    [[self objectFetcher] setSentDataSelector:sentDataSel];
  }
}
```

After that in  MyViewController.m written like this

```
 [self.driveService setUploadProgressBlock:^(GTLServiceTicket *ticket, unsigned long long numberOfBytesRead, unsigned long long dataLength) {
  NSLog(@"uploading");
 
}];
```

Above NSLog never getting excused because of this I am unable to get uploaded data bytes. By debugging I come across as **uploadProgressBlock_** always showing nil. may be this resone my block handler not getting executed.

Please suggest me if I did any mistake to work it out.
If any one have idea to get the bytes of data uploaded to google drive for a file please suggest me. Your suggestions are more useful to my work.

Thanks in advance.

**Consolidated Answer by taking our folks suggestions:**

Here is the code to get upload progress information

```
GTLServiceTicket *uploadTicket= [self.driveService executeQuery:query completionHandler:^(GTLServiceTicket *ticket,GTLDriveFile *updatedFile,NSError *error)
        {
            if (error == nil)
            {
                [self.delegate completedFileUploadingToGoogleDrive];
                NSError *fileDeletionError=nil;
                [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:absalutePath error:&fileDeletionError];
            } else
            {
                [self.delegate errorOccoredWhileUploadingToGoogleDrive:error];
            }
        }];
        
        [uploadTicket setUploadProgressBlock:^(GTLServiceTicket *ticket, unsigned long long totalBytesWritten, unsigned long long totalBytesExpectedToWrite) {
            [self.delegate uploadedFileInfoInKB:(float)totalBytesExpectedToWrite/1024 and:(float)totalBytesWritten/1024];
        }];
```

Happy Coding!!

Comment: hi ajay i need your help,i have done google integration and i have successfully upload audio file to google i need to show progress bar while upload audio file to google drive if you aware of this concept suggest me how can i do this?

Comment: @Ravindhiran Please see my question I have edited and given code for the answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have succeeded in using the upload block callback... assign it to the `GTLServiceTicket` object you obtain from the `executeQuery` method.

**Sample:**

```
GTLServiceTicket *uploadTicket =  [self.driveService executeQuery:query  completionHandler:^(GTLServiceTicket *ticket,  GTLDriveFile *insertedFile, NSError *error) 
                                           { // completion 
                                           }];


        [uploadTicket setUploadProgressBlock:^(GTLServiceTicket *ticket, unsigned long long totalBytesWritten, unsigned long long totalBytesExpectedToWrite) 
         {
             // progress
         }
```

Answer (score 1):

I recently used FabioL's answer but in Swift 2.3, it looks like this

```
    let serviceTicket = service.executeQuery(query, completionHandler:  { (ticket, insertedFile , error) -> Void in
        let myFile = insertedFile as? GTLDriveFile

        if error == nil {
            alert.title = "Image Uploaded"
            alert.message = "100%"
            if progressView != nil {
                progressView!.progress = 1
            }
        } else {
            print("An Error Occurred! \(error)")
            alert.title = "There was an error uploading"
        }
    })

    //update UI on progress
    serviceTicket.uploadProgressBlock = {(ticket, written, total) in
        if progressView != nil {
            let progressCalc: Float = (Float(written)/Float(total))
            alert.message = "\(progressCalc*100)%"
            progressView!.progress = progressCalc
        }
    }
```

As the upload happens it updates a ProgressView and on completion it changes the title and message of an UIAlertViewController

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it may have to do with the lack of the `NS_BLOCKS_AVAILABLE` #define having been set in your project.  If so, then instead of using `-setUploadProgressBlock:`, I think you need to define a method like:

```
        - (void)ticket:(GTLServiceTicket *)ticket
 hasDeliveredByteCount:(unsigned long long)numberOfBytesRead
      ofTotalByteCount:(unsigned long long)dataLength;
```

And then specify it as the callback to use in your code, like:

```
 [self.driveService setUploadProgressSelector:@selector(ticket:hasDeliveredByteCount:ofTotalByteCount:)];
```

(Search for `uploadProgressSelector` in GTLService.h; there's a comment there that may be helpful.)