# Showing a progress bar when uploading file to google drive with swift 3

Tags: file-upload, swift3, request, google-drive-api

I'm currently developing an application in swift 3 for a school project that requires uploading files to google drive . 
The upload is currently working , but i need to inform users with an upload bar.
Here the current code

```
let folderId: String = folders[indexPath.row].folderId
    let metadata = GTLRDrive_File.init()
    metadata.name = "Ruin.mp3"
   // metadata.mimeType = "application/vnd.google-apps.photo"
    metadata.parents = [folderId]

    guard let filePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Ruin", ofType: "mp3") else {
        return
    }
    guard let fileData = FileManager.default.contents(atPath: filePath) else {
        return
    }


    let uploadParameters = GTLRUploadParameters(data: fileData , mimeType: "audio/mpeg")
    uploadParameters.shouldUploadWithSingleRequest = true
    let query = GTLRDriveQuery_FilesCreate.query(withObject: metadata, uploadParameters: uploadParameters)
    query.fields = "id"
    self.service.executeQuery(query, completionHandler: {(ticket:GTLRServiceTicket, object:Any?, error:Error?) in
        if error == nil {
            //  print("File ID \(files.identifier)")

        }
        else {
            print("An error occurred: \(error)")
        }
    })
```

Thanx in advance

Comment: You may refer with this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15267191/never-getting-uploading-data-progress-in-google-api-for-ios) even if it was written in objective-c. You may use the upload block callback thenassign it to the `GTLServiceTicket` object you obtain from the `executeQuery` method.

Comment: @abielita thank you for your response , i tried many solution implemented in objective c but there is no method called uploadProgressBlock in GTLRServiceTicket